# Wordpress can't use ZipArchive

Tags: php, plugin-development, headers, ziparchive

Im currently developing a site where customers can download brand images like packshots. Ive made a custom cart where the client should be able to download all images added to the cart using ZipArchive. But it dosent seem to work as easy if it was not WordPress(as it usually is).

My code:

```
$files = array('test.jpg', 'test2.jpg');
$zipname = 'images.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

At first i had Error:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at

but i managed fixing this using the init action.

The second problem was that no zip was downloaded.

My question is if anyone here have worked with ZipArchive in WP that would be able to show some samplecode. Or have any tips that may work.

Thanks.

Comment: Where and how is this code run?

Comment: @JacobPeattie In a plugin that i'm building. The plugin overwrites the woocommerce cart.php and that's where this code should run.

Comment: It doesn’t really make sense for cart.php to be a zip download like this. When are users supposed to be able to download these files?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I totally agree but this is a budget project and WooCommerce has the functionality and fields required for the project. So this was a good solution instead of developing all the product and cart functionality. https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/6129028?key=b9b8b522628202e5b7deed560963d8b2

Comment: @JacobPeattie also ZipArchive doesn't work no matter if it's a cart page or any page in WordPress.

Comment: I suspect the image files you are trying to add to the ZIP archive are not found. ZipArchive won't create the ZIP file if the files you are trying to add to the archive are not found. I suggest adding the direct file path to the test image files to see if then at least the ZIP archive is created.

Comment: @fredriktv No, I mean that cart.php is a template that only occupies a portion of the page, but your code is setting headers and trying to output the contents of a zip file. It doesn’t make sense. You need some kind of custom URL that runs your code instead of any templates. This is going to be more difficult than dropping your code into a template, since you mentioned budget. WooCommerce let’s you add downloadable files to products. Is there a reason you’re not just using that. Regardless, WooCommerce is off topic here, so this is not a great place to ask this.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully created zip file in root folder of WordPress using following code:

```
$files = array(__DIR__.'/test.jpg', __DIR__.'/screenshot.png');
$zipname = 'images.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE) or die(' cant open ');
foreach ($files as $file) {
 if( $zip->addFile($file)){
    echo "<br>$file Added To Zip Sucessfully";
 }else {
    echo "<br>Can not add $file file";
 }

}
$zip->close();


if(file_exists($zipname)){
    echo "<a href='$zipname' download> Download $zipname</a> ";
}else{
    echo "$zipname not Exists!";
}
```

I give a full path of images using `__DIR__`  and test each step by printing messages. you can provide a download link if it is not automatically downloaded.  I hope it helps.